# Query for current salary based on date

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

```
id       name      salary      date
1        aaa       10000     10/2/2014
1        aaa       15000     06/04/2015
1        aaa       20000     16/07/2016
1        aaa       25000     10/04/2017
```

If an employee got salary hike every year,
how can I get an employee's current year salary?
That query should be working fine for every year.

If I execute it in 2013 it displays 2013 year salary, if execute in 2016 it displays 2016 year salary, similarly, for 2017 also it would be display 2017 salary.

Comment: Are you using `MySQL` or `Oracle`?

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Oracle? (Different products, different date/time functions.)

Comment: I tried below command
        `code` select * from table name where date=now(); `code`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this [**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c6fc8/4) for MySQL

```
SELECT
  SUM(salary) as salary
FROM salary
WHERE YEAR(STR_TO_DATE(date, '%d/%m/%Y')) = YEAR(CURDATE())
GROUP BY id
```

Answer (score 0):

in Mysql you can do like this:

```
select * form tablename where YEAR(now()) = YEAR(fieldname)
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution for **ORACLE**

```
SELECT *
FROM SALARY_TABLE
WHERE NAME = 'whatever_the_name_is'
AND TRUNC(HIKE_DATE,'YYYY') = TRUNC(SYSDATE,'YYYY');
```

Sample query with dummy data

```
WITH SALARY_TABLE AS -- Sample data queried from DUAL
  (SELECT 1                            AS ID,
    'aaa'                              AS name,
    10000                              AS salary,
    TO_DATE('10/2/2014', 'dd/mm/yyyy') AS hike_date
  FROM dual
  UNION
  SELECT 2, 'aaa', 15000, TO_DATE('06/04/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') FROM dual
  UNION
  SELECT 3, 'aaa', 20000, TO_DATE('16/07/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy') FROM dual
  UNION
  SELECT 3, 'aaa', 25000, TO_DATE('10/04/2017', 'dd/mm/yyyy') FROM dual
  )
SELECT * -- Actual solution
FROM SALARY_TABLE
WHERE NAME                     = 'aaa'
AND TRUNC(HIKE_DATE,'YYYY') = TRUNC(SYSDATE,'YYYY');
```